# how connect rasa stack chatbot with whatsapp without Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, rasa

I made a chatbot with rasa stack and I would like to use it in WhatsApp, I explored twilio, but I would like to know if there are more options that allows the implementation. Twilio is a little bit expensive and complicate to me and some clients don't like for the high price.
I'm using `rasa/rasa: 2.7.2`, have anyone found another alternative for twilio?

Comment: could you tell us what you have found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only WhatsApp alternative is WhatsApp business, which is likely more expensive as you need to have a business license with them. Unfortunately their API is not public like most messaging services are.

Comment: is there any updates regarding this question